# Angular Material Datepicker ISO_8601 Format

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using an angular material datepicker.

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="form_birthdate" name="form_birthdate" placeholder="Choose a date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The date should be in `ISO_8601` format. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just convert your date through standard JS function.

```
var event = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
console.log(event.toString());
// expected output: Wed Oct 05 2011 16:48:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
// (note: your timezone may vary)

console.log(event.toISOString());
// expected output: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: I dont want to set this afterwards, i want to format it using the datepicker.

Comment: Try to check this one: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5722. They said you should create your adapter so you can format/convert data to custom format.

Comment: This was actually really useful, thanks for this answer. I kept thinking of the value as a string, instead of converting it back to a date. Totally makes sense, like... duh. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

Works like this:

(in app.module.ts)

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    // ... 
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, // <-- import this reference
      useValue: {
        parse: {
          dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD', // <-- for manual editing
        },
        display: {
          dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD', // <-- for displaying
          monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
          dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
          monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
        },
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

[image]

(manual editing also works)